# Adicionar oauth a API com autenticação tradicional

Tags: php, oauth2

Quando o utilizador abre o site, é redirecionado para o formulário de login onde ocorre a autenticação.

Do lado do servidor é verificado as credenciais e uma sessão é criada, desde modo a aplicação consegue aceder as mensagens, posts, dados pessoais, etc... do utilizador em questão través de chamadas a API restfull.

Surgiu a necessidade de dar permissão a terceiros para aceder aos dados do utilizador.
Quero alterar a API para aceitar autenticação via oauth.

Quando uma requisição é feita a API, é verificado se a sessão existe para permitir o acesso mas no caso do oauth teria que ignorar a sessão e verificar se o token é válido.

Uma solução seria utilizar o oauth no próprio site, ou seja, o site seria cliente da API com autenticação oauth, eliminando a necessidade de uma sessão.

A questão é, quando uma aplicação de terceiros tenta aceder a API, o utilizador terá que permitir o acesso através de um login no site. Com isso em mente, se o site também é cliente da API, não seria um looping?

Comment: Você já realizou algum teste utilizando o OAuth 2.0?